Entity Checkboxes: How to have one value displayed in form but another value in preview and submission?
I want to use Entity Checkboxes (referens to a node type) to display the Title from nodes as checkboxes in the form but to display another field from the node (my_text) in submission.
Tried to use Submission Display in Advanced tab but do not understand it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Example:
The values in a node:
title: "Beach" (shows in form)
my_text: "I prefer photographs of beaches" (shows in preview and submission)
EDIT: There is a "Item format" under the "Submission display" in Advanced Tab witch allows us to choose "Custom". I assume that this can be done with some Twig. Is it correct?

Does this answer your question? Show entity reference content with a field other than the title

I figured it out :-)
I added a new field to the node "Short name" and to the reffered view and hid the title from display.
In Advanced Tab: Submission display: show "Label" - it then shows the title of the node that can hold the longer text.
There is probably a fancier way, but this will do :-)
